# React Native State not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a header component with a FlatList inside it. When I select an item in the FlatList I need to use that as state in the Screen component. The state seems to be only giving me the previous state.

### Header Component

```
function HomeHeader({ categories, contentOffsetY, handleSelectedCategory }) {
  const FLAT_LIST_REF = useRef(null);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);

  const selectCategory = (category, index) => {
    if (selectedCategory === category) {
      handleSelectedCategory(null);
      setSelectedCategory(null);
    } else {
      handleSelectedCategory(category);
      setSelectedCategory(category);
      scrollToIndex(index);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item, index }) => {
      return (
        <Pressable onPress={() => selectCategory(item, index)}/>
      );
    },
    [selectedCategory]
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
        ref={FLAT_LIST_REF}
        horizontal
        data={categories}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={itemSeparatorComponent}
        contentContainerStyle={contentContainerStyle}
      />
  )
}
```

### Home Screen Component

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null);
  
  const handleSelectedCategory = (category) => {
    setSelectedCategory(category);
    console.log(selectedCategory?.id);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <HomeHeader
        categories={categories}
        contentOffsetY={contentOffsetY}
        handleSelectedCategory={handleSelectedCategory}
      />
      {loading ? (
        <HomeSkeleton />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Animated.FlatList
            ref={flatListRef}
            // THE OTHER PROPS
          />
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: `console.log(selectedCategory?.id);` will show you the previous state value because the component hasn't rerendered yet by that point (and hence updated the `selectedCategory` state). If you log `category.id` that's being passed to the function, then you should see the latest category.

Answer (score 0):

Would Like to change the approach a little bit

lets keep the selectedCategory state in screen component, and set the value through props, first

Second you don't need if (selectedCategory === category) check to set a state, react is intelligent enough to know its the same old value, you can try consoling..

I have changed a little bit to make the UI work, but you can change as per you need
https://snack.expo.dev/n-6XULO7N

And all set!